# How is the "training error" of KNN plotted?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

On [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall07/L4_knn.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Teaching/CS340-Fall07/L4_knn.pdf)
Page 6

The author (Kevin Murphy) plots the training and test errors associated with kNN classifer.

I am not sure how training error is derived, since for kNN there is no training phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Training error” means an error calculated on the train set. You are correct that $k$NN is not “trained”, but still there is a difference between the train and test set performance—for   $k=1$ it can return the same data point and reach perfect results. The plot in the paper shows an error rates on the $y$-axis and on the $x$-axis different degrees of freedom understood as $k/n$ for different models.